# Removing partially similar entries based on a value from a single column in CSV

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I have CSV table which is a list of tweets from different users over time. The dataset includes tweets and reposts which are identical except for hashtags or additional comments added by another user. For example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 11/03/2022 | We have a new president! |
| 13/03/2022 | We have a new president! #newpresident |
| 14/03/2022 | My mom is a president. |
| 14/03/2022 | RT @user: We have a new president! What is going to happen? |

All the rows that contain "We have a new president!" are seen as duplicate for me and I need to get rid of them, so the original row #1 and #3 are the only ones I need. I tried running this:

```
import csv
import re

csvInput = open('input.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='')
csvOutput = open('output.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='')

csvReader = csv.reader(csvInput)
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvOutput)
prevRows = set()

for row in csvReader:
    if row[2] in prevRows or re.sub('^RT @.*: ', '', row[2]) in prevRows:
        continue
    prevRows.add(row[2])
    csvWriter.writerow(row)

csvOutput.close()
csvInput.close()
```

Doesn't do the trick. Is there a way to modify this or a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pandas module could be quite useful:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('input.csv').loc[~df['Column B'].str.contains('(#.+$|^RT @.+)')].to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

PS. not tested